# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.../thinc/backends/_custom_kernels.cu'

Tags: pyinstaller

I'm doing a executable with Pyinstaller, based in an app of tkinter. I compile the executable using  `pyinstaller simple.py --additional-hooks-dir=.` .My app need a lot of packages to do the functions. For this reason I build a script (`hook-space.py`) to collect all necessary packages, or I suppose this do it. This file has the follow code:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# ----------------------------- SPACY -----------------------------
data = collect_all("spacy")

datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]

# ----------------------------- THINC -----------------------------
data = collect_all("thinc")

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- CYMEM -----------------------------
data = collect_all("cymem")

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- PRESHED -----------------------------
data = collect_all("preshed")

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- BLIS -----------------------------

data = collect_all("blis")

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

datas = collect_data_files("es_core_news_sm")
```

When I compiled the file .spec, the exe file was build correctly but when I use a function in the executable, I obtain the follow error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "simple.py", line 133, in calcular
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "predictors.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "textclassification.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "utils.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "spacy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "thinc/api.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "thinc/initializers.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "thinc/backends/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "thinc/backends/cupy_ops.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "thinc/backends/_custom_kernels.py", line 37, in <module>
  File "pathlib.py", line 1221, in read_text
  File "pathlib.py", line 1208, in open
  File "pathlib.py", line 1063, in _opener
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../ejecutable/dist/simple/thinc/backends/_custom_kernels.cu'
```

Comment: This problem doesn't have anything to do with `tkinter`, right? If so please remove the `tkinter` tag.

Comment: Not an expert, but maybe you are rewriting `datas` at the end? `datas = collect_data_files("es_core_news_sm")` And you were previously saving everything from the libraries into a list called `datas` as well?

Comment: Initially, I didn't it, but in another blog, I saw that is necessary do this to call the pre-trained model of spacy, because spacy by default doesn't have this pertained model. @VladimirVargas

Comment: @NicolasParraAvila I don't understand. I'm saying that you are REDEFINING `datas` on top of a list `datas` that contained the information of the libraries.

Comment: @VladimirVargas I understand you already,  I will try change this part to  `datas+= collect_data files("es_core_news_sm") `

Comment: @NicolasParraAvila that works if `collect_data_files` returns a list, otherwise it won't work

Comment: @VladimirVargas Yes, this works! but i have other error jajaja but is different.